# Matlab R2014a stepwiselm generates an infinite loop

Tags: matlab

I am using stepwiselm for some data analysis.  I've run into an error several times in which an "infinite" loop is generated using stepwiselm and I can't figure out how to break the loop without stopping my script.  Stepwiselm works by determining a starting model for the data, then by adding or removing terms to improve the model prediction (based on user specified criterion--I am using BIC).  Each time a change is made, it is displayed on the screen.  The infinite loop occurs when the same predictors are removed, then added back into the model.  Has anyone else had this problem?

Example: (screen display as function is running--not actual display but you get the idea)

```
.
.
.
15. remove x1:x3 BIC 52
16. remove x4:x2 BIC 49
17. remove x5 BIC 47
18. add x4:x2 BIC 46
19. add x5 BIC 45
20. add x1:x3 BIC 55
21. remove x1:x3 BIC 52
.
.
.
.
50. remove x1:x3 BIC 52
51. remove x4:x2 BIC 49
52. remove x5 BIC 47
53. add x4:x2 BIC 46
54. add x5 BIC 45
55. add x1:x3 BIC 55
56. remove x1:x3 BIC 52
.
.
.
85. remove x1:x3 BIC 52
86. remove x4:x2 BIC 49
87. remove x5 BIC 47
88. add x4:x2 BIC 46
89. add x5 BIC 45
90. add x1:x3 BIC 55
91. remove x1:x3 BIC 52
.
.
.
.
```

Continue until I stop the script

---

some code as requested: 
predictors = [300,10]; %data set with 300 rows and 10 columns
response_var = [300,1]; %data to predict with 300 rows and 1 column
md_len = stepwiselm(predictors, response_var, 'interactions', 'Upper', 'interactions', 'Criterion', 'BIC');

Comment: Just ran my code again and had the same problem.  This is the actual display:
18. Removing x2:x4, BIC = 117.79
19. Removing x2:x3, BIC = 114.02
20. Adding x2:x4, BIC = 100.5952
21. Adding x2:x3, BIC = 95.5492
22. Removing x2:x4, BIC = 117.79
.
.
198. Removing x2:x4, BIC = 117.79
199. Removing x2:x3, BIC = 114.02
200. Adding x2:x4, BIC = 100.5952
201. Adding x2:x3, BIC = 95.5492
202. Removing x2:x4, BIC = 117.79
.
.
2058. Removing x2:x4, BIC = 117.79
2059. Removing x2:x3, BIC = 114.02
2060. Adding x2:x4, BIC = 100.5952
2061. Adding x2:x3, BIC = 95.5492
2062. Removing x2:x4, BIC = 117.79
.
.

Comment: It would help to see how you are calling `stepwiselm` including all options you're setting. Presumably you're getting stuck in a loop where the criteria for adding (`PEnter`) and criteria for removing (`PRemove`) are fulfilled at each step and it therefore never finds a stopping point.  It is possible that either your criteria for stopping are too strict, or that the type of model you're trying to fit is not a good match for your data.

Comment: See changes to original post--sample code added at the bottom.